# help in understanding hybrid analysis results? Mac

Tags: malware, virus, antivirus, antimalware, virus-removal

So I have a few PDFs on my computer I got online a few years ago on my Mac computer.

When I ran a virus total scan on some of them I got a couple that were concerning. Here is the one that most concerned me:  https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/3163f47f0820f5e4ac7a22d2fd55b19e363d529b3b8a36ea58756f6318550031/behavior

However, when I used hybrid analysis rusts came back saying  everything was clear for windows, but the system could not run it for MacOS. Specifically, it said it is "not supported." Here are the results I got: https://hybrid-analysis.com/sample/3163f47f0820f5e4ac7a22d2fd55b19e363d529b3b8a36ea58756f6318550031

I then downloaded Malwarebytes and scanned my Mac, everything looked good there.

so all in all I am confused. A few quick questions:

1. why did hybrid analysis not work for Mac? I tried multiple PDFs and all of them do not work. I am wondering if this is because the file is not able to infect a Mac? (I hope that is the case at least?)
2. is this file and the other ones like it likely infected? I don't see anything concerning the than the "behavior" section in virus total. And if it is infected is my Mac infected or would this only influence a windows?

Thank you!!